# Convert a 1D array into a 'rotated' 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, algorithms, matrix

simply put, let's say I have this array - `[1 2 1]`
I want to try and get this output in Matlab

> [1 1 1
>
> 1 2 1
>
> 1 1 1]

It's like my array was 'rotated' into forming the above matrix such that if I start at any peripheral element and move through the center of the matrix (in a straight line of course) towards the other end, then I get back my original array ( `[1 2 1]` )

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Does your array always have an odd number of elements? Also note that you can't start 'at any periphal' element, but only at the center elements of the periphal rows and columns and at the 4 corner points (try it for a 5x5 matrix and you'll see what I mean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the length of the array is odd and that the array is symmetrical. Also note that from your requirements not all elements of the resulting matrix are specified. Those elements will be zero in the code shown below.

```
v=[1,2,3,2,1];      % odd-length array
A=diag(v);
A=A+rot90(A);
n=(length(v)+1)/2;
A(n,:)=v;
A(:,n)=v;
A =

1   0   1   0   1
0   2   2   2   0
1   2   3   2   1
0   2   2   2   0
1   0   1   0   1
```